# Reference-needed or citation-needed or reference-request, which tag?

Tags: support, tag

[reference-needed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-needed), [citation-needed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-needed) and [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) are synonymous to each other. All of them have at least 2 questions on the main site.

> **Meaning of tags:** Reference from Qur'an, Hadith, and other acceptable sources are needed.

**Which tag would be more appropriate keeping in mind the readability, memorability, length, etc. ?**

And requesting the admins to make the others synonyms.

Comment: see also http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77/how-should-the-reference-request-tag-be-used

Answer (score 6):

[reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) is what other SE sites use. It sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

We can't have this problem already :-(.

In this case, we have to just get rid of two of them, and keep one. I would go with [citation-needed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation-needed) but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

[reference-needed] sounds better to me.

Comment: +1 Give me a break from wikipedia styled "citation" messages. lol